# class template with tuple declaration

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic-templates

I have a problem with building project with code attached bellow. I wrote the TemplClass and build the project with no error. When I wrote a method dostuff(), called it in main function and build the project, an error message "use of undefined type ...(see code related to tuples)" was raised during build.

Where is the problem? I am fairly new to cpp. But experienced in c#. I don't understand the relation between the error message and the code provided.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Note: The code is just an excerpt from a school homework.

EDIT: Error messages added
EDIT2: Retexter added [here](http://rextester.com/BQNX38035)

```
// main.cpp
int main()
{
    using namespace namespace1;
    dostuff("", 0, 0.0);
    return 0;
}

//otherfile.hpp
namespace namespace2
{

    template<typename ... TL>
    class TemplClass
    {
    public:
        TemplClass(TL ...pl): storedParams(pl...)
        {
            //Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
            //Error C2027   use of undefined type 'std::tuple<const char (&)[1],int,double>'    advcpp.split     
          //c:\users\jry\source\repos\advcpp.split\advcpp.split\test01split.hpp 12  


            auto storedParamsLoc = std::tuple<TL ...>(pl...);

        }


    private:

    //Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    //Error C2079   'namespace2::TemplClass<const char (&) 
    //[1],int,double>::storedParams' uses undefined class 'std::tuple<const char (&) 
    //[1],int,double>'  advcpp.split     
    //c:\users\jry\source\repos\advcpp.split\advcpp.split\test01split.hpp   25  
        std::tuple<TL ...> storedParams;
    };

}

namespace namespace1
{
    template<typename ...TL>
    namespace2::TemplClass<TL ...> dostuff(TL && ...pl)
    {
        return namespace2::TemplClass<TL...>(pl...);
    }

}
```

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, always include the actual errors in the question. Copy-paste them, as text and in full and complete and without modifications.

Comment: That's not complete, in full, unmodified or copy-pasted. Mark *all* or the error text and copy-paste it into its own "code" block in the question, then mark the lines where the errors are in the code with comments. Compilers tend to add informational notes that could be really helpful to see.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error somewhere like here http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc

Comment: @Yola The link to rextester was added [here](http://rextester.com/BQNX38035). Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: I can't see any `#include` in your code, and `std::tuple` isn't magically available

Comment: @papagaga That's it. It would take me ages to see that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With provided example on rextester, it's clear that you forgot to include the header for tuple.

```
#include <tuple>
```